# Who is George H. Murphy, author of "Iskander at the Bridge"?

Tags: poetry, identification-request

I am trying to identify who George H. Murphy is? He wrote a poem entitled "Iskander at the Bridge" in 1903 in The News & Observer, [Raleigh, N.C.] November 01, 1903, p. 3.

Comment: **[Iskander at the Bridge](https://www.newspapers.com/newspage/80455731/)**

With loud huzzas and cheers,
Brandishing their spears.
And waving round their ears
Their keen Damascus blades,
A score of horsemen dash; 
And jeweled daggers flash.

Answer (score 3):

With so little to go on, it is difficult to be certain. It is possible that the person in question was a Consul General at Large of the United States.

The [published poem](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85042104/1903-11-01/ed-1/seq-3/) gives his location as Washington DC. which makes the *diplomatic* George H Murphy the more likely candidate of those individuals thrown up by internet searches.

This reference to him in a [List of Consular Officers of the United States Corrected to July 23, 1907](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2212482?seq=1) gives his place of birth as North Carolina, which may tie in with his submitting a work to a newspaper 200 plus miles away.

if this is the correct [George H Murph](https://politicalgraveyard.com/bio/murphy4.html#832.74.08)y, he got around a bit

> Murphy, George Herbert (1860-1924) — also known as George H. Murphy — Born in Scuppernong, Washington County, N.C., September 28, 1860. School teacher; U.S. Vice & Deputy Consul in Chemnitz, 1886-89; Bremen, 1899-1900; Magdeburg, 1900; U.S. Deputy Consul General in Berlin, 1889-90; U.S. Vice & Deputy Consul General in Berlin, 1890; Frankfort, 1900-04; U.S. Consular Agent in Hanover, 1890-93; SAINT Catherines, 1905-06; U.S. Vice Commercial Agent (Vice Consul) in Luxembourg, 1893-96; U.S. Vice Consul in Colón, 1898; U.S. Consul General in , 1906-14; Cape Town, 1914-20; Zurich, 1920-24. Died in Zurich, Switzerland, October 16, 1924 (age 64 years, 18 days). Interment at St. Matthew's Episcopal Churchyard, Hillsborough, N.C.